# if $\beta\in \mathcal{O}\cap\mathbb{Q}[\mathbb{w}]$, then $\beta=a_{0}+a_1w+...+a_{p-1}w^{p-1}$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

$w=e^\frac{2i}{p}$ where p is odd prime. $\mathbb{Z}[]$

if $\beta\in \mathcal{O}\cap\mathbb{Q}[\mathbb{w}]$, then $\beta=a_{0},+a_1w+...+a_{p-1}w^{p-1}$ where $a_i's$ are unique integers

this  a theorem in algebraic number theory.

the $disc(w-1)=disc(w)=p^{p-2}$.

in the part of the proof:

it says $\beta$ can be written as $\beta$ =$\frac{a_0+a_1(w-1)+...+a_{p-1}(w-1)^{p-1}}{p^{p-2}}$

with $a_i\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p^{p-2} \ |a_i^2$

the part I do not understand comes now:(please explain the part below)

why it remains to show that if $\beta$ =$\frac{a_0+a_1(w-1)+...+a_{p-1}(w-1)^{p-1}}{p}$

then $a_0=a_1=...=a_{p-1}=0 (mod$ $ p)$

what happens to the deonominator $p^{p-2}$?

Comment: If you are asking about a proof you found somewhere, it might help to let people know where you found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean the proof for showing that $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ is the ring of integers of the cyclotomic number field $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta]$, with $w=\zeta=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}$. In the proof it is needed that the discriminant is $D(1,\zeta,\ldots ,\zeta^{p-1})=\pm p^{p-2}$. This can be shown by using the norm. Then this result gives
$$
p^{p-2}\mathcal{O}_K ⊆ Z[ζ] ⊆ \mathcal{O}_K,
$$
so that really equality holds (applying another result on ramification): $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$. I guess that is your question "what happens to the denominator $p^{p-2}$".

Of course, $\beta\in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ means that we have
$$
\beta=a_0+a_1\zeta +\cdots +a_{p-1}\zeta^{p-1},
$$
with unique integers $a_i$.

Comment: could you please explain why $D=p^{p-2}$ gives the result you indicated.